# I'm getting syntax error when using if condition in Laravel view file

Tags: laravel

```
@foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
    <div>
       <h3> You ordered {{$pizza['type']}} pizza for {{$pizza['price']}} rupees; </h3>

        @if({{$pizza['price']}} > 50)

            <p>This Pizza is Expensive</p>

        @elseif({{$pizza->['price']}} < 50)

            <p>This Pizza is lower price</p>

        @elseif({{$pizza->['price']}} == 50)

            <p>This Pizza is everage price</p>

        @endif    

    </div>
@endforeach
```

I know to do this in php. but how to do this in laravel. i'm beginner to laravel. So i'm getting syntax error. please help to go ahead. Thank you...

This is the syntex error

```
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\pizzahouse\resources\views\pizza.blade.php)
```

Comment: Please post the error and the corresponding line in which the error occurs.

Comment: I attached the error

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the opening `{{` and closing `}}` tags for variables inside the `@if` statements. And also you are using the wrong notation to access arrays.

```
@foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
    <div>
       <h3> You ordered {{$pizza['type']}} pizza for {{$pizza['price']}} rupees; </h3>

        @if($pizza['price'] > 50)

            <p>This Pizza is Expensive</p>

        @elseif($pizza['price'] < 50)

            <p>This Pizza is lower price</p>

        @elseif($pizza['price'] == 50)

            <p>This Pizza is everage price</p>

        @endif

    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please remember marking the answer as correct so others know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

this line :

```
 @if({{$pizza['price']}} > 50)
```

should be :

```
 @if($pizza['price'] > 50)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. How does this solve the permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
@foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
<div>
   <h3> You ordered {{$pizza['type']}} pizza for {{$pizza['price']}} rupees; </h3>

    @if($pizza['price'] > 50)

        <p>This Pizza is Expensive</p>

    @elseif($pizza['price'] < 50)

        <p>This Pizza is lower price</p>

    @elseif($pizza['price'] == 50)

        <p>This Pizza is everage price</p>

    @endif    

</div>
@endforeach
```

you cant acces to array with this : ->